# Cannot call CancelEdit() inside an OnRowChanging event

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
private void Cource_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //fill dataset by using .GetAllCourses() function 
    DataSet ds = new DataAccess.newCourcesDAC().GetAllCourses();

    //define and set BindingSource to tblCourses of dataset
    BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
    BS.DataSource = ds;
    BS.DataMember = "tblCourses";

    //bind datagridview to Bindingsource
    ds.Tables["tblCourses"].RowChanging += new  DataRowChangeEventHandler(Cource_RowChanging);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = BS;

    //bind for texbox to navigat 4 column of Cource table
    txtCourseID.DataBindings.Add("Text", BS, "CourseID");
    txtCourseName.DataBindings.Add("Text", BS, "CourseName");
    txtPrequest.DataBindings.Add("Text", BS, "Prequest");
    txtCourseContent.DataBindings.Add("Text", BS, "CourseContent");
}
**void Cource_RowChanging(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.Action==DataRowAction.Add)
        {
            if (((int)e.Row["CourseID", DataRowVersion.Proposed]) < 10)
            {
                e.Row.SetColumnError("CourseID", "cource id must < 10");
                e.Row.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }**
```

i have a dataset(ds) with a table(tblCourse) with 4 columns that using a bindingsource is binded to 4 textbox.
i want to validate data when adding a new record to datatable by RowChanging event.

i want to cancel row with [ e.Row.CancelEdit();] when occured a specified condision.

but i recive this error:
Cannot call CancelEdit() inside an OnRowChanging event.  Throw an exception to cancel this update.

Comment: Did you try to "Throw an exception to cancel this update"?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone who might stumble across this old thread, I'll post a solution that addresses some "gotchas" related to this problem.

1. Despite what the error message says, throwing an exception in RowChanging in conjunction with a Try-Catch will not remove the new row. I cannot say that it *never* removes the row when an error is thrown, only that I haven't seen it happen yet.
2. Throwing an exception without a Try-Catch will mark the row as having errors. If you have any WPF datagrid code to indicate validation errors - such as displaying a red check mark as I'm fond of - then the error will be displayed correctly. The row will not be removed though.
3. Calling e.Delete in RowChanging also will not remove the row under any conditions I've seen to date. If you set a breakpoint and check the RowState, it will be set to Detached. When the RowChanged event fires next, the RowState will revert to e.Added. Even if it is possible to delete a row in RowChanging under some other conditions, that probably won't reset any identity columns in your dataset or backend database back to their last value, prior to the addition.
4. My fairly simple VB.Net workaround below uses a flag variable (I usually put mine at the data class level) to identify whether a cancellation has occurred in RowChanging, then takes the appropriate actions in RowChanged and resets the flag. So far I haven't encountered any issues with this, except for some "This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data. BeginEdit() will allow the creation of new data in this row." exceptions elsewhere in my code when the deleted rows were encountered, which were fixed with some simple checks for RowState set to Detached. I hope this helps.

   Private LastRowAdditionCanceled As Boolean

   ```
   Public Sub RowChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataRowChangeEventArgs)

        If e.Action = DataRowAction.Add Then
       'Add the conditions where you want to cancel the row addition above
       LastRowAdditionCanceled = True
         End If
   End Sub



   Public Sub RowChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataRowChangeEventArgs)

         If LastRowAdditionCanceled = False Then
            'execute your usual RowChanged code here

         Else
               e.Row.RejectChanges()
               LastRowAdditionCanceled = False
         End If
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use the event "RowChanged" and you can call e.Row.Delete() if you want to delete that row.
I'm attaching sample code where you can see that if the inserted value was "2" the row is deleted:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dt_RowChanged);

        dataTable.Rows.Add(1);
        dataTable.Rows.Add(2);
        dataTable.Rows.Add(3);

        Console.WriteLine("Total rows: {0}", dataTable.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow item in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["ID"]);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void dt_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
        {
            if (((int)e.Row["ID"]) == 2)
            {
                e.Row.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```